# Accessing previous element for the Runge-Kutta 2nd order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, ode

```
from math import sin
def rk(f,x0,t0,h,N):
    t = t0
    xlist = x0
    while t < N*h:
        klist = f(t,xlist) #GIVES ME K1
        xlist = [x+h *k for x,k in zip(xlist, klist)] 

        llist = [u * 0.5*h for u in klist] #GIVES ME 1/2 Y1
        t += h
```

The midpoint method (Runge-Kutta 2nd order) the equation goes like this:

`K1 = f(t, x)
K2 = f(t0 + 1/2*h, x0 + 1/2*K1*h)
yn+1 = yn + k2*h`

So far, my `klist` combined with the `xlist` give me `K1`, My `llist` gives me the `1/2*k1*h` portion of the `K2` equation. I'm having trouble accessing the previous element in `klist` to be able to add that element to my `llist`. So for example

```
print (klist, llist)
[0.0]    [0.0]
[0.84]   [0.42]
[-0.52]  [-0.026]
```

And I want to add the previous element of the `klist` per midpoint method to the 1/2*k1*h. so it would look like `0.84 + 0.5*-0.52*h`

I've tried doing `[q + l for q, l  in zip(llist, klist[1:])]` but it doesn't work since my `klist` returns `[0.0], [0.84], [-0.52], etc...` and so `klist[1:]` would just return `[]`. So how would go about this? I tried making a list of lists, but when it came to adding the values, I would just get an error since I can't add a float to the list. Also for the `yn+1` equation, how would I add those since they would also be different types ?

Comment: In addition to what was said in the answer: Please reconsider your coding style: 1) Do not overwrite variables to use them for another purpose. 2) Do not use two variables for the same thing (e.g., `t` and `t0`). 3) Encapsulate your vector operations in separate functions to avoid having to distinguish between components and vectors on a level where you do not need it 4) Make your notation consistent: For example, you are switching between `x` and `y`.

Comment: Also, I do not believe that `print (klist, llist)` really had the output you are claiming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method reads, including an intermediate state, as

```
k1 = f(t, x)
xm = x + 0.5*h*k1
k2 = f(t + 0.5*h, xm)
x  = x + h*k2
```

which should be list-ified as

```
k1list = f(t, xlist)
xmlist = [ x + 0.5*h*k1 for x,k1 in zip(xlist,k1list)]
k2list = f(t + 0.5*h, xmlist)
xlist  = [ x + h*k2 for x,k1 in zip(xlist,k2list)]
```

---

As told previously multiple times, the `+` operator applied to lists in python is not element-wise addition but list concatenation. If you want to use vector arithmetic you have to use a dedicated vector class such as `numpy.array`